# IActionModelConvention registration in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

How can I register `IActionModelConvention` in ASP.NET Core 3.1? I have a class that implements it:

```
class MyConvention : IActionModelConvention {
   ...
}
```

This is how to register it in .NET Core 2.1:

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
    options.Conventions.Add(new MyConvention());
});
```

How can I use `MyConvention` with ASP.NET Core Endpoint Routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

Within your startup class inside `ConfigureServices` method use this `services.'desired service lifetime'<IActionModelConvention, MyConvention>()`

Services life time can be either Transient, Scoped or Singleton, further information you can find in [Service Lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes)

Also take a look at the following article from Microsfto's documentation: [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

I use this code:

```
 builder.Services.AddControllers(
      o=>o.Conventions.Add(new CustomConvention())
    );
```